# Mule ESB: All Routing Message Processor has a weird output

Tags: esb, mule

I have an All Routing Message Processor where I send a request from a Client to multiple External services , I can send the request and I get the response but the response looks a bit weird:

```
<java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList serialization="custom">
<java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList>
<default/>
<int>2</int>
<byte-array>PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz48IS0tIFB1Ymxpc2hlZCBieSBK
QVgtV1MgUkkgYXQgaHR0cDovL2pheC13cy5kZXYuamF2YS5uZXQuIFJJJ3MgdmVyc2lvbiBpcyBK
QVgtV1MgUkkgMi4xLjYuIC0tPjwhLS0gR2VuZXJhdGVkIGJ5IEpBWC1XUyBSSSBhdCBodHRwOi8v
amF4LXdzLmRldi5qYXZhLm5ldC4gUkkncyB2ZXJzaW9uIGlzIEpBWC1XUyBSSSAyLjEuNi4gLS0+
PGRlZmluaXRpb25zIHhtbG5zOnNvYXA9Imh0dHA6Ly9zY2hlbWFzLnhtbHNvYXAub3JnL3dzZGwv
c29hcC8iIHhtbG5zOnRucz0iaHR0cDovL21pbml3ZWJzZXJ2aWNlLyIgeG1sbnM6eHNkPSJodHRw
Oi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAxL1hNTFNjaGVtYSIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly9zY2hlbWFzLnhtbHNv
YXAub3JnL3dzZGwvIiB0YXJnZXROYW1lc3BhY2U9Imh0dHA6Ly9taW5pd2Vic2VydmljZS8iIG5h
bWU9IkhhbGxvV2VsdEltcGxTZXJ2aWNlIj4KPHR5cGVzPgo8eHNkOnNjaGVtYT4KPHhzZDppbXBv
cnQgbmFtZXNwYWNlPSJodHRwOi8vbWluaXdlYnNlcnZpY2UvIiBzY2hlbWFMb2NhdGlvbj0iaHR0
cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo0NDM1L21pbml3ZWJzZXJ2aWNlL21pbml3ZWJzZXJ2aWNlP3hzZD0xIi8+
CjwveHNkOnNjaGVtYT4KPC90eXBlcz4KPG1lc3NhZ2UgbmFtZT0iaGFsbG8iPgo8cGFydCBuYW1l
PSJwYXJhbWV0ZXJzIiBlbGVtZW50PSJ0bnM6aGFsbG8iLz4KPC9tZXNzYWdlPgo8bWVzc2FnZSBu
YW1lPSJoYWxsb1Jlc3BvbnNlIj4KPHBhcnQgbmFtZT0icGFyYW1ldGVycyIgZWxlbWVudD0idG5z
OmhhbGxvUmVzcG9uc2UiLz4KPC9tZXNzYWdlPgo8cG9ydFR5cGUgbmFtZT0iSGFsbG9XZWx0Ij4K
PG9wZXJhdGlvbiBuYW1lPSJoYWxsbyI+CjxpbnB1dCBtZXNzYWdlPSJ0bnM6aGFsbG8iLz4KPG91
dHB1dCBtZXNzYWdlPSJ0bnM6aGFsbG9SZXNwb25zZSIvPgo8L29wZXJhdGlvbj4KPC9wb3J0VHlw
ZT4KPGJpbmRpbmcgbmFtZT0iSGFsbG9XZWx0SW1wbFBvcnRCaW5kaW5nIiB0eXBlPSJ0bnM6SGFs
bG9XZWx0Ij4KPHNvYXA6YmluZGluZyB0cmFuc3BvcnQ9Imh0dHA6Ly9zY2hlbWFzLnhtbHNvYXAu
b3JnL3NvYXAvaHR0cCIgc3R5bGU9ImRvY3VtZW50Ii8+CjxvcGVyYXRpb24gbmFtZT0iaGFsbG8i
Pgo8c29hcDpvcGVyYXRpb24gc29hcEFjdGlvbj0iIi8+CjxpbnB1dD4KPHNvYXA6Ym9keSB1c2U9
ImxpdGVyYWwiLz4KPC9pbnB1dD4KPG91dHB1dD4KPHNvYXA6Ym9keSB1c2U9ImxpdGVyYWwiLz4K
PC9vdXRwdXQ+Cjwvb3BlcmF0aW9uPgo8L2JpbmRpbmc+CjxzZXJ2aWNlIG5hbWU9IkhhbGxvV2Vs
dEltcGxTZXJ2aWNlIj4KPHBvcnQgbmFtZT0iSGFsbG9XZWx0SW1wbFBvcnQiIGJpbmRpbmc9InRu
czpIYWxsb1dlbHRJbXBsUG9ydEJpbmRpbmciPgo8c29hcDphZGRyZXNzIGxvY2F0aW9uPSJodHRw
Oi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjQ0MzMvbWluaXdlYnNlcnZpY2UvbWluaXdlYnNlcnZpY2UiLz4KPC9wb3J0
Pgo8L3NlcnZpY2U+CjwvZGVmaW5pdGlvbnM+</byte-array>
<byte-array>PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz48IS0tIFB1Ymxpc2hlZCBieSBK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<java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList serialization="custom">
<java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList>
<default/>
<int>2</int>
<byte-array>PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz48IS0tIFB1Ymxpc2hlZCBieSBK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</byte-array>
<byte-array>PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz48IS0tIFB1Ymxpc2hlZCBieSBK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 GlvbnM+</byte-array>  Pgo8L3NlcnZpY2U+CjwvZGVmaW5pdGlvbnM+</byte-array>
</java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList>
</java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList>
```

Any suggestion how to solve this?

Update :

Here is my current configuration :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:core="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf" xmlns:tcp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tcp" xmlns:jms="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="CE-3.2.1" xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/current/mule-cxf.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tcp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tcp/current/mule-tcp.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/current/mule-jms.xsd ">
    <flow name="flows1Flow1" doc:name="flows1Flow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:4433/miniwebservice" mimeType="text/xml" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <logger level="INFO" category="ddo" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <all doc:name="All">
            <processor-chain>
                <message-properties-transformer mimeType="text/xml" doc:name="Message Properties">
                    <add-message-property key="http.method" value="#[header:INBOUND:http.method]"/>
                </message-properties-transformer>
                <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:4435/miniwebservice#[header:INBOUND:http.request]" mimeType="text/xml" doc:name="HTTP"/>
                <mulexml:xslt-transformer maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5" xsl-file="C:\Users\kiesa\Desktop\XSLReplace.xsl" doc:name="XSLT"/>
            </processor-chain>
            <processor-chain>
                <message-properties-transformer mimeType="text/xml" doc:name="Message Properties">
                    <add-message-property key="http.method" value="#[header:INBOUND:http.method]"/>
                </message-properties-transformer>
                <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:4434/miniwebservice#[header:INBOUND:http.request]" mimeType="text/xml" doc:name="HTTP"/>
                <mulexml:xslt-transformer maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5" xsl-file="C:\Users\kiesa\Desktop\XSLReplace2.xsl" doc:name="XSLT"/>
            </processor-chain>
        </all>
        <custom-aggregator failOnTimeout="true" class="customJavaClass" doc:name="Custom Aggregator"/>
        <mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer doc:name="Object to XML"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to solve here: the result of an [All Routing Message Processor](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Routing+Message+Processors#RoutingMessageProcessors-All) is a java.util.List of payloads received from each call to each message processor inside the All one.

You must have an object-to-xml transformation configured somewhere: this is why the List payload is turned into XML by using an XStream-powered serialization.

You need to deal with this list, for example with a custom component that can process a java.util.List payload.

Comment: thats what i was thinking in the first place but i couldt find out how to pass the list to my java class.

Comment: So did you find out? If not, expand the above question with your configuration. Otherwise please accept this answer.

Comment: Excellent. I've reviewed my response. Instead of a custom aggregator, use a simple component that accepts a java.util.List. For example add processResponses(java.util.List responses) in customJavaClass.

Comment: you mean something like that ?         <component class="customJavaClass" doc:name="Java">
            <singleton-object class="java.util.List"/>
        </component>  I took Java component  set the class  to my customJavaClass  and as an object I added the java.utilt.list

Comment: ok, but how do i actualy pass the list that goes in to the component to my customJavaClass ? or is it being done by mule

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7819/discussion-between-david-dossot-and-kiesa)

Comment: hey, can you give me a  hand for a last time ? im getting an exception while returning an message via Client , Idk if this still belongs to this question or if I have to make a new one

Comment: here is the new question : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334912/mule-esb-cannot-copy-message-with-a-stream-payload)