# Mule ESB : Cannot copy message with a stream payload

Tags: esb, mule

I have a Mule Application where I send a Request to Multiple WebServices and aggregate the List of responses i get , the idea is to get the first response of the List by returning it from the CustomJavaClass where the list is handled :

```
return responses.get(0);
```

I am able to reach the WSDL if I try to reach it over a Browser , the returned WSDL looks like its supposed to look . But i I try to send a message via SoapUi i get the following exception :

```
Exception stack is:
1. Cannot copy message with a stream payload. Payload type is "org.apache.commons.httpclient.ContentLengthInputStream". Message payload is of type: ContentLengthInputStream (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.routing.outbound.AbstractSequenceRouter:73 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.api.MessagingException: Cannot copy message with a stream payload. Payload type is "org.apache.commons.httpclient.ContentLengthInputStream". Message payload is of type: ContentLengthInputStream
    at org.mule.routing.outbound.AbstractSequenceRouter.route(AbstractSequenceRouter.java:73)
    at org.mule.routing.outbound.AbstractOutboundRouter$1.doInTransaction(AbstractOutboundRouter.java:102)
    at org.mule.routing.outbound.AbstractOutboundRouter$1.doInTransaction(AbstractOutboundRouter.java:99)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

SOAPUi Exception :

```
Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.api.processor.MessageProcessors$LifecyleAwareMessageProcessorWrapper@ceb6dd. Message payload is of type: ContentLengthInputStream
```

my current configurations :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:core="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf" xmlns:tcp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tcp" xmlns:jms="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="CE-3.2.1" xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/current/mule-cxf.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tcp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tcp/current/mule-tcp.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/current/mule-jms.xsd ">
    <flow name="flows1Flow1" doc:name="flows1Flow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:4433/miniwebservice" encoding="UTF-8" mimeType="text/xml" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <logger level="INFO" category="ddo" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <all doc:name="All">
            <processor-chain>
                <message-properties-transformer encoding="UTF-8" mimeType="text/xml" doc:name="Message Properties">
                    <add-message-property key="http.method" value="#[header:INBOUND:http.method]"/>
                </message-properties-transformer>
                <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:4435/miniwebservice#[header:INBOUND:http.request]" encoding="UTF-8" mimeType="text/xml" doc:name="HTTP"/>
                <mulexml:xslt-transformer mimeType="text/xml" maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5" xsl-file="C:\Users\kiesa\Desktop\XSLReplace.xsl" doc:name="XSLT"/>
            </processor-chain>
            <processor-chain>
                <message-properties-transformer encoding="UTF-8" mimeType="text/xml" doc:name="Message Properties">
                    <add-message-property key="http.method" value="#[header:INBOUND:http.method]"/>
                </message-properties-transformer>
                <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:4434/miniwebservice#[header:INBOUND:http.request]" encoding="UTF-8" mimeType="text/xml" doc:name="HTTP"/>
                <mulexml:xslt-transformer mimeType="text/xml" maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5" xsl-file="C:\Users\kiesa\Desktop\XSLReplace2.xsl" doc:name="XSLT"/>
            </processor-chain>
        </all>
        <mulexml:xml-to-object-transformer doc:name="XML to Object"/>
        <component class="CustomJavaClass" doc:name="Java"/>
        <byte-array-to-string-transformer ignoreBadInput="true" encoding="UTF-8" mimeType="text/xml" doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Getting the WSDL works because the GET request carries no payload. But when you try to invoke a SOAP method, the POST payload is an InputStream, which of course can't be dispatched several times.

Thus: serialize the HTTP input stream with a:

```
<object-to-byte-array-transformer />
```

right after the http:inbound-endpoint.

Comment: How to resolve similar problem as above here:
I am using **Mule 4.2.1 Anypoint Studio 7.3.4:**
`Payload can be transformed by using an <object-to-byte-array-transformer> in order to be able to copy the message. Payload type is "org.mule.runtime.core.internal.streaming.bytes.ManagedCursorStreamProvider"`