# Mule Runtime 4.2.1 Anypoint 7.3.4: Cannot copy message with a stream payload

Tags: anypoint-studio, mule-esb, mulesoft, mule4

Facing below runtime error after upgrading from `Mule Runtime 4.2.0 to 4.2.1.`

Below detailed my codebase, and quick error message, and detailed error logs for review. Please suggest, if anyone faced the same problem?

I referred to other similar question and answer in StackOverflow [Mule ESB : Cannot copy message with a stream payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334912/mule-esb-cannot-copy-message-with-a-stream-payload), this doesn't solve mine below error.

**Runitime Error on Mule 4.2.1:**

```
Cannot copy message with a stream payload. Payload can be transformed by using an <object-to-byte-array-transformer> in order to be able to copy the message. Payload type is "org.mule.runtime.core.internal.streaming.bytes.ManagedCursorStreamProvider"
```

**Detailed Error Log**

```
INFO  2019-08-05 11:29:15,388 [[MuleRuntime].cpuLight.11: [jda-demand-adapter].Get_BY_Status_n_Update_Part_Flow.CPU_LITE @7ed56bee] [event: 20e0d4f1-b746-11e9-afb2-0a0027000005] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: BY status: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<DeliveryStatus>
  <DeliveryID>46658</DeliveryID>
  <Username>user_di_test</Username>
  <StartDelivery>2019-08-05T05:24:34.886502+00:00</StartDelivery>
  <LastProcessed>2019-08-05T05:46:16.508861+00:00</LastProcessed>
  <Status>LOADED</Status>
  <ParameterInfo>
    <Category>Events</Category>
    <Version>1.14.17</Version>
    <File>Events.gz</File>
  </ParameterInfo>
  <Statistics>
    <DeliveredRecords>323</DeliveredRecords>
    <PendingRecords>323</PendingRecords>
    <ProcessedRecords>0</ProcessedRecords>
    <ErroneousRecords>0</ErroneousRecords>
  </Statistics>
</DeliveryStatus>

INFO  2019-08-05 11:29:15,397 [[MuleRuntime].cpuIntensive.09: [jda-demand-adapter].Get_BY_Status_n_Update_Part_Flow.CPU_INTENSIVE @6b417a92] [event: 20e0d4f1-b746-11e9-afb2-0a0027000005] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: payload : {
  "DeliveryStatus": {
    "DeliveryID": "46658",
    "Username": "user_di_test",
    "StartDelivery": "2019-08-05T05:24:34.886502+00:00",
    "LastProcessed": "2019-08-05T05:46:16.508861+00:00",
    "Status": "LOADED",
    "ParameterInfo": {
      "Category": "Events",
      "Version": "1.14.17",
      "File": "Events.gz"
    },
    "Statistics": {
      "DeliveredRecords": "323",
      "PendingRecords": "323",
      "ProcessedRecords": "0",
      "ErroneousRecords": "0"
    }
  }
}
INFO  2019-08-05 11:29:15,410 [[MuleRuntime].cpuIntensive.09: [jda-demand-adapter].Get_BY_Status_n_Update_Part_Flow.CPU_INTENSIVE @6b417a92] [event: 20e0d4f1-b746-11e9-afb2-0a0027000005] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Delivery Status summary: "46658","LOADED", {
  "DeliveredRecords": "323",
  "PendingRecords": "323",
  "ProcessedRecords": "0",
  "ErroneousRecords": "0"
}
INFO  2019-08-05 11:29:17,030 [[MuleRuntime].io.110: [jda-demand-adapter].Update_Part_Status_Recordcount_Flow.BLOCKING @502d3ddf] [event: 20e0d4f1-b746-11e9-afb2-0a0027000005] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Final response for Job without Errors, jobDetails: null
INFO  2019-08-05 11:29:17,032 [[MuleRuntime].io.110: [jda-demand-adapter].Update_Part_Status_Recordcount_Flow.BLOCKING @502d3ddf] [event: 20e0d4f1-b746-11e9-afb2-0a0027000005] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Inside Aggregation complete - For loop payload:[org.mule.runtime.api.metadata.TypedValue@fc4ba33d]
INFO  2019-08-05 11:29:17,052 [[MuleRuntime].io.110: [jda-demand-adapter].Update_Part_Status_Recordcount_Flow.BLOCKING @502d3ddf] [event: 20e0d4f1-b746-11e9-afb2-0a0027000005] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: After Reporting Transformation: {
  "Summary": {
    "DataPostingStatus": "",
    "DataPostingDetailedStatus": "",
    "JobCreatedDate": "",
    "JobRestartDate": "",
    "JobLastModifiedTime": "",
    "JobExecutionDuration": "",
    "JobExecutionDuration_in_Secs": "",
    "RecordsProcessed": "",
    "DeliveredRecords": "323",
    "PendingRecords": "323",
    "ProcessedRecords": "0",
    "ErrorRecords": "0",
    "Categories": [
      "Events"
    ]
  },
  "CategorySummary": [
    {
      "Category": "Events",
      "DeliveredRecords": "323",
      "PendingRecords": "323",
      "ProcessedRecords": "0",
      "ErrorRecords": "0",
      "DeliveryId": [
        "46658"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Errors": {

  },
  "Details": [
    {
      "DeliveryStatus": {
        "DeliveryID": "46658",
        "Username": "user_di_test",
        "StartDelivery": "2019-08-05T05:24:34.886502+00:00",
        "LastProcessed": "2019-08-05T05:46:16.508861+00:00",
        "Status": "LOADED",
        "ParameterInfo": {
          "Category": "Events",
          "Version": "1.14.17",
          "File": "Events.gz"
        },
        "Statistics": {
          "DeliveredRecords": "323",
          "PendingRecords": "323",
          "ProcessedRecords": "0",
          "ErroneousRecords": "0"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
ERROR 2019-08-05 11:29:17,076 [[MuleRuntime].cpuLight.11: [jda-demand-adapter].Ingestion_Status_Main_Flow.CPU_LITE @7132a277] [event: 20e0d4f1-b746-11e9-afb2-0a0027000005] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.exception.OnErrorContinueHandler: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Cannot copy message with a stream payload. Payload can be transformed by using an <object-to-byte-array-transformer> in order to be able to copy the message. Payload type is "org.mule.runtime.core.internal.streaming.bytes.ManagedCursorStreamProvider".
Element               : Get_Job_Status_Details_Flow/processors/1 @ jda-demand-adapter:com/jda/cd/common/flow/ingestion-status.xml:257 (Scatter-Gather)
Element XML           : <scatter-gather doc:name="Scatter-Gather">
                        <route>
                        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="Calculating the Job Satus ..."></logger>
                        <flow-ref name="GetDetailedJobStatus_SubFlow" doc:name="GetDetailedJobStatus_SubFlow"></flow-ref>
                        <set-payload value="#[{
  "detailedStatus": vars.detailedStatus
}]" mimeType="application/java" doc:name="Set Payload" doc:id="5ea3c7bf-b1b1-4231-9af3-c8e39f241866"></set-payload>
                        </route>
                        <route>
                        <flow-ref name="Get_Job_Details_Flow_Enricher_0" doc:name="Get_Job_Details_Flow_Enricher_0"></flow-ref>
                        <set-payload value="#[{
  "jobStatus": vars.jobStatus
}]" mimeType="application/java" doc:name="Set Payload" doc:id="e0a78803-a93c-4523-9551-4cf9218f059b"></set-payload>
                        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger Job Details" doc:id="8b31e869-5630-4e01-902d-3e259ba2734e" message="Scatter-Gather Get_Job_Details_Flow_Enricher_0 payload:#[payload], jobStatus:#[vars.jobStatus]"></logger>
                        <choice doc:name="CalcJobStatus_IfNeeded-Choice">
                        <when expression="#[vars.jobStatus == 'IN_PROGRESS']">
                        <async doc:name="Async">
                        <flow-ref name="CalcBatchStatus_Flow" doc:name="CalcBatchStatus_Flow"></flow-ref>
                        </async>
                        </when>
                        <otherwise>
                        <logger message="job status is final" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"></logger>
                        </otherwise>
                        </choice>
                        </route>
                        <route>
                        <flow-ref name="Get_Records_By_Status_SubFlow_Enricher_1" doc:name="Get_Records_By_Status_SubFlow_Enricher_1"></flow-ref>
                        <set-payload value="#[{
  "recordsByStatus": vars.recordsByStatus
}]" mimeType="application/java" doc:name="Set Payload"></set-payload>
                        </route>
                        <route>
                        <logger message="#["jobExecution Duration : "]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"></logger>
                        <flow-ref name="Get_Job_Status_Details_Flow_Enricher_2" doc:name="Get_Job_Status_Details_Flow_Enricher_2"></flow-ref>
                        <logger message="payload last_mod_date #[vars] #[vars.lastModDate]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"></logger>
                        <flow-ref name="Get_Job_Status_Details_Flow_Enricher_6" target="jobCreatedDate" targetValue="#[payload[0].CREATED_DATE]" doc:name="Get_Job_Status_Details_Flow_Enricher_6"></flow-ref>
                        <set-variable value="#[now()]" doc:name="Current time" doc:id="547a11d2-b9dc-479e-a0c4-36e5b367bcee" variableName="currentTime"></set-variable>
                        <set-variable value="#[%dw 2.0 import * from dw::util::Timer output application/java --- ((toMilliseconds(vars.lastModDate) - toMilliseconds(vars.jobCreatedDate))/1000) as Number as String {format: ".##"}]" doc:name="Set Variable jobExecutionDurationSeconds" doc:id="499b7eda-f565-4a7c-94bd-9aeaf7306941" variableName="jobExecutionDurationSeconds"></set-variable>
                        <set-variable value="#[%dw 2.0 import * from dw::util::Timer output application/java --- ((toMilliseconds(vars.currentTime) - toMilliseconds(vars.lastModDate))/1000) as Number as String {format: ".##"}]" doc:name="TimeSinceLastMod" doc:id="0f30996f-1c89-4d45-90e9-915f3d2440bb" variableName="timeSinceLastMod"></set-variable>
                        <set-variable value="#[%dw 2.0 output application/json --- (((vars.jobExecutionDurationSeconds / 3600) as Number) as String {format: ".##"}) ++ ":" ++ ((((vars.jobExecutionDurationSeconds mod 3600) as Number) / 60 as Number) as String)as String {format: ".##"} ++ ":" ++((((vars.jobExecutionDurationSeconds mod 60) as Number))as String) as String {format: ".##"}]" doc:name="Set Variable jobExecutionDuration" doc:id="eaa22fce-6085-4290-8a31-46fc0bdd90c0" variableName="jobExecutionDuration"></set-variable>
                        <set-variable value="#[%dw 2.0 output application/json --- (((vars.timeSinceLastMod / 3600) as Number) as String) as String {format: ".##"} ++ ":" ++ ((((vars.timeSinceLastMod mod 3600) as Number) / 60 as Number) as String) as String {format: ".##"} ++ ":" ++((((vars.timeSinceLastMod mod 60) as Number))as String) as String {format: ".##"}]" doc:name="Set Variable TimeSinceLastModString" doc:id="15942ccf-d219-40f1-a783-3e4466bdfbbf" variableName="timeSinceLastModString"></set-variable>
                        <logger message="job_create date #[vars]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"></logger>
                        <set-payload value="#[%dw 2.0 output application/json --- {"jobExecutionDuration": vars.jobExecutionDuration,  "jobExecutionDurationSeconds": vars.jobExecutionDurationSeconds, "jobCreatedDate":vars.jobCreatedDate,"lastModDate": vars.lastModDate,"currentTime": vars.currentTime,"timeSinceLastMod": vars.timeSinceLastMod}]" doc:name="Set Payload" doc:id="a97e5020-9d64-411e-87bf-ab325f29cd7f" mimeType="application/json"></set-payload>
                        </route>
                        </scatter-gather>
Error type            : MULE:UNKNOWN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.runtime.api.exception.MuleRuntimeException: Cannot copy message with a stream payload. Payload can be transformed by using an <object-to-byte-array-transformer> in order to be able to copy the message. Payload type is "org.mule.runtime.core.internal.streaming.bytes.ManagedCursorStreamProvider"

********************************************************************************
```

Below Codebase works fine in Mule 4.2.0, after upgrading Mule runtime to 4.2.1 and trying to use Anypoint 7.3.4, getting above runtime error. I am not getting the clue to fix it.

**Below same code works on Mule 4.2.0:**

```
    <flow name="Ingestion_Status_Main_Flow" doc:description="Ingestion_Status_Main_Flow will read BY_delivery_IDs and try to read the status of the delivery from BY. If BY service is not available, then it provides the status of the status tables.  In addition to the BY response details, it shows the job's current status, Number of records as per the status. ">
        <http:listener path="${secure::ingestion.status.resource}/{jobId}" allowedMethods="GET" doc:name="/status" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Config">
            <http:response statusCode="#[migration::HttpListener::httpListenerResponseSuccessStatusCode(vars)]"/>
            <http:error-response statusCode="#[vars.statusCode default migration::HttpListener::httpListenerResponseErrorStatusCode(vars)]"/>
        </http:listener>

        <logger message='#[attributes.uriParams.jobId]' level="INFO" doc:name="Job ID from input" />
        <set-variable variableName="jobId" value="#[attributes.uriParams.jobId]" doc:name="jobId" />
        <set-variable value="#[attributes.queryParams.notify]" doc:name="notifyFlag" doc:id="c2c8a869-4941-4f72-9cd3-3c9ea7441e65" variableName="notify"/>
        <flow-ref name="Validate_Input_JobID_Sub_Flow" doc:name="Validate_Input_JobID_Sub_Flow" />

        <set-variable variableName="correlationId" value="#[vars.jobId]" doc:name="Session Variable"/>
        <flow-ref name="Fetch_Parts_for_Job_SubFlow" doc:name="Fetch_Parts_for_Job_SubFlow" />
        <set-variable value="#[sizeOf(payload)]" doc:name="sizeOfPayload" doc:id="0ab10eae-0b50-4b37-bd89-0ac614f548db" variableName="sizeOfPayload" />
        <logger message='Delivery ID for Job: #[payload.BY_DELIVERY_ID]' level="INFO" doc:name="Deliver IDs" />

        <choice doc:name="Choice">
            <when expression="#[sizeOf(payload) &gt; 0]">
                    <foreach doc:name="For Each" doc:id="742d1496-9be5-409a-a42c-e0da8a1a696d" >
                    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger For Each" doc:id="e9aeff5c-e00c-4fd4-ada3-09b22f4161cd" message="inside for each #[payload] "/>
                    <flow-ref doc:name="Get_BY_Status_n_Update_Part_Flow" doc:id="6e00a6b0-8d83-4df6-b22a-ce6666fed36a" name="Get_BY_Status_n_Update_Part_Flow"/>
                    <aggregators:group-based-aggregator doc:name="groupByDeliveryId" doc:id="b4b76fac-3f35-4812-9c1d-81b23ddd1eb9" name="groupByDeliveryId" groupSize="#[vars.sizeOfPayload]" >
                        <aggregators:incremental-aggregation >
                            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="f3e2bdd1-d660-4074-92b0-4c04ea421706" message="Incremental size #[sizeOf(payload)]" />
                        </aggregators:incremental-aggregation>
                        <aggregators:aggregation-complete >
                            <logger message="Final response for Job without Errors, jobDetails: #[vars.detailedStatus]" level="INFO" doc:name="Response without Errors included" />
                            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="eb7c7626-7091-481a-939c-926f938d84ae" message="Inside Aggregation complete - For loop payload:#[payload]" />
                            <ee:transform doc:name="Reporting Transformation" doc:id="421fb819-c58f-4f46-8d6d-e5dfa43df133">
                                <ee:message>
                                    <ee:set-payload resource="ingestion\ingestion-status-resp.dwl" />
                                </ee:message>
                            </ee:transform>
                            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="f6acf89c-5b84-4cbc-9cab-bf4b9e48da4f" message="After Reporting Transformation: #[payload]"/>
                            <set-variable variableName="aggregatedPayload" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Set Variable" doc:id="eded53f3-18ac-4a84-8fcf-916e89d7a185"/>
                        </aggregators:aggregation-complete>
                    </aggregators:group-based-aggregator>
                </foreach>

            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <logger message="No Delivery IDs found." level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
                <set-payload value="#[{&#xA;  &quot;Summary&quot;: {&#xA;    &quot;DataPostingStatus&quot;: '',&#xA;    &quot;DataPostingDetailedStatus&quot;: '',&#xA;    &quot;JobCreatedDate&quot;: '',&#xA;    &quot;JobRestartDate&quot;: '',&#xA;    &quot;JobLastModifiedTime&quot;: '',&#xA;    &quot;JobExecutionDuration&quot;: '',&#xA;    &quot;JobExecutionDuration_in_Secs&quot;: '',&#xA;    &quot;RecordsProcessed&quot;: ''&#xA;  }&#xA;}]" mimeType="application/json" doc:name="Set Payload" doc:id="066c7871-dd4b-4bde-8663-e0558a5847df"/>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>

        <set-payload value="#[vars.aggregatedPayload]" doc:name="Set Payload" doc:id="337a0771-458c-4511-920c-ca38fcb8c6d9" />
        <logger message='getting db details #[payload]' level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

        <flow-ref name="Ingestion_Status_Main_Flow_Enricher_22" doc:name="Ingestion_Status_Main_Flow_Enricher_22"/>
        <set-payload value="#[vars.aggregatedPayload]" doc:name="Set Payload" doc:id="7ef033ba-17d6-4597-9b4c-96fb73212e63" />
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="794cfad2-e368-4b44-9c7e-746e0e692338" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json  
---
{
  Summary: {
    DataPostingStatus: vars.jobStatus,
    DataPostingDetailedStatus: vars.detailedStatus,
    JobCreatedDate: vars.jobCreatedDate,
    JobRestartDate: "",
    JobLastModifiedTime: vars.lastModDate,
    JobExecutionDuration: vars.jobExecutionDuration,
    JobExecutionDuration_in_Secs: vars.jobExecutionDurationSeconds,
    RecordsProcessed: "",
    DeliveredRecords: payload.Summary.DeliveredRecords,
    PendingRecords: payload.Summary.PendingRecords,
    ProcessedRecords: payload.Summary.ProcessedRecords,
    ErrorRecords: payload.Summary.ErrorRecords,
    Categories: payload.Summary.Categories,
  },
  Errors:{},
  CategorySummary: payload.CategorySummary,
  Details: payload.Details
}]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
        <logger message='Getting errors details...' level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <flow-ref name="Add_Errors_to_Payload_Sub_Flow_Enricher_0" doc:name="Add_Errors_to_Payload_Sub_Flow_Enricher_0"/>
       <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="5b0518ac-139a-42f8-ae12-a42cce2449c1" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload
]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
        <async doc:name="Async">
            <choice doc:name="Choice">
                <when expression="#[vars.notify == 'true']">
                    <flow-ref name="Send_Status_Mail_Flow" doc:name="Send_Status_Mail_Flow" />
                </when>
                <otherwise>
                    <logger message="Notification flag is not provided as query parameter." level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
                </otherwise>
            </choice>
        </async>

        <logger message='Final response: #[payload]  jobId: #[vars.jobId]' level="DEBUG" doc:name="Response with Errors" />

        <logger message="Ingestion status request done" level="INFO" doc:name="Status request completed" />

        <error-handler ref="Global_Errorflow_Choice_Exception_Strategy" doc:name="Global Exception Strategy" />

    </flow>

    <sub-flow name="Ingestion_Status_Main_Flow_Enricher_22">
        <flow-ref name="Get_Job_Status_Details_Flow" doc:description="Job status retrieved from status tables."/>
    </sub-flow>
</flow>


   <sub-flow name="Get_Job_Status_Details_Flow" doc:description="Job status retrieved from status tables.
    For now, different stages of the job processing has been reported.
    1. Batches not yet created.
    2. Batches created, and parts are getting creating.
    3. Parts are created, and processing.
    4. Some part uploads are failed.
    5. Some parts processing is failed i.e. payload is not created. ">
        <scatter-gather doc:name="Scatter-Gather">
            <route>
                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="Calculating the Job Satus ..." />
                <flow-ref name="GetDetailedJobStatus_SubFlow" doc:name="GetDetailedJobStatus_SubFlow" />
                <set-payload value="#[{&#xA;  &quot;detailedStatus&quot;: vars.detailedStatus&#xA;}]" mimeType="application/java" doc:name="Set Payload" doc:id="5ea3c7bf-b1b1-4231-9af3-c8e39f241866"/>
            </route>
            <route>
                <flow-ref name="Get_Job_Details_Flow_Enricher_0" doc:name="Get_Job_Details_Flow_Enricher_0"/>
                <set-payload value="#[{&#xA;  &quot;jobStatus&quot;: vars.jobStatus&#xA;}]" mimeType="application/java" doc:name="Set Payload" doc:id="e0a78803-a93c-4523-9551-4cf9218f059b"/>
                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger Job Details" doc:id="8b31e869-5630-4e01-902d-3e259ba2734e" message="Scatter-Gather Get_Job_Details_Flow_Enricher_0 payload:#[payload], jobStatus:#[vars.jobStatus]"/>
                <choice doc:name="CalcJobStatus_IfNeeded-Choice">
                    <when expression="#[vars.jobStatus == 'IN_PROGRESS']">
                        <async doc:name="Async">
                            <flow-ref name="CalcBatchStatus_Flow" doc:name="CalcBatchStatus_Flow" />
                        </async>
                    </when>
                    <otherwise>
                        <logger message="job status is final" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
                    </otherwise>
                </choice>
            </route>
            <route>
                <flow-ref name="Get_Records_By_Status_SubFlow_Enricher_1" doc:name="Get_Records_By_Status_SubFlow_Enricher_1"/>
                <set-payload value="#[{&#xA;  &quot;recordsByStatus&quot;: vars.recordsByStatus&#xA;}]" mimeType="application/java" doc:name="Set Payload" />
            </route>
            <route>
                <logger message='#["jobExecution Duration : "]' level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
                <flow-ref name="Get_Job_Status_Details_Flow_Enricher_2" doc:name="Get_Job_Status_Details_Flow_Enricher_2"/>
                <logger message='payload last_mod_date #[vars] #[vars.lastModDate]' level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
                <flow-ref name="Get_Job_Status_Details_Flow_Enricher_6" target="jobCreatedDate" targetValue="#[payload[0].CREATED_DATE]" doc:name="Get_Job_Status_Details_Flow_Enricher_6"/>
                <set-variable value="#[now()]" doc:name="Current time" doc:id="547a11d2-b9dc-479e-a0c4-36e5b367bcee" variableName="currentTime"/>
                <set-variable value='#[%dw 2.0
import * from dw::util::Timer
output application/java
---
((toMilliseconds(vars.lastModDate) - toMilliseconds(vars.jobCreatedDate))/1000) as Number as String {format: ".##"}]' doc:name="Set Variable jobExecutionDurationSeconds" doc:id="499b7eda-f565-4a7c-94bd-9aeaf7306941" variableName="jobExecutionDurationSeconds"/>
                <set-variable value='#[%dw 2.0
import * from dw::util::Timer
output application/java
---
((toMilliseconds(vars.currentTime) - toMilliseconds(vars.lastModDate))/1000) as Number as String {format: ".##"}]' doc:name="TimeSinceLastMod" doc:id="0f30996f-1c89-4d45-90e9-915f3d2440bb" variableName="timeSinceLastMod"/>
                <set-variable value='#[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
(((vars.jobExecutionDurationSeconds / 3600) as Number) as String {format: ".##"}) ++ ":" ++ ((((vars.jobExecutionDurationSeconds mod 3600) as Number) / 60 as Number) as String)as String {format: ".##"} ++ ":" ++((((vars.jobExecutionDurationSeconds mod 60) as Number))as String) as String {format: ".##"}]' doc:name="Set Variable jobExecutionDuration" doc:id="eaa22fce-6085-4290-8a31-46fc0bdd90c0" variableName="jobExecutionDuration"/>
                <set-variable value='#[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
(((vars.timeSinceLastMod / 3600) as Number) as String) as String {format: ".##"} ++ ":" ++ ((((vars.timeSinceLastMod mod 3600) as Number) / 60 as Number) as String) as String {format: ".##"} ++ ":" ++((((vars.timeSinceLastMod mod 60) as Number))as String) as String {format: ".##"}]' doc:name="Set Variable TimeSinceLastModString" doc:id="15942ccf-d219-40f1-a783-3e4466bdfbbf" variableName="timeSinceLastModString"/>
                <logger message='job_create date #[vars]' level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
                <set-payload value='#[%dw 2.0 output application/json --- {"jobExecutionDuration": vars.jobExecutionDuration,  "jobExecutionDurationSeconds": vars.jobExecutionDurationSeconds, "jobCreatedDate":vars.jobCreatedDate,"lastModDate": vars.lastModDate,"currentTime": vars.currentTime,"timeSinceLastMod": vars.timeSinceLastMod}]' doc:name="Set Payload" doc:id="a97e5020-9d64-411e-87bf-ab325f29cd7f" mimeType="application/json"/>
            </route>
        </scatter-gather>
        <logger message="Flowvars used to invoke the restart-flows: payload: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="RestartFlags - Logger" />
    </sub-flow>
```

Comment: Its a bug, i guess sub flow is not able to access variables `vars.detailedStatus`,`vars.jobStatus`, `vars.recordsByStatus` .Try using dataweave to create these variables instead of set variable.

Comment: I do not agree on your guess, if your guess would have been right, then Mule is intelligent enough to complain about it, the variables you guesses are getting populated in scatter-gather itself, the error occurring before accessing those variables. And moreover same code works fine with Mule runtime 4.2.0 without any such errors.

Comment: You can raise case with Muesoft, your code is breaking before entering scatter-gather. I have followed your error message down and its breaking in sub flow after mainflow logger `After Reporting Transformation`. Actually i has same issue and it worked for me, strange though.

Comment: This is a bug. Please refer [this](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/question/0D52T00004nuUgwSAE/fix-for-studio-735-mule-421-scattergather-usage-fails-with-error-cannot-copy-message-with-a-stream-payload) link for more information.